# Volume of a 3D torus as a form on a quotient space

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, quotient-spaces

I'm trying to calculate the volume form $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ on $\mathbb{T}^3=\mathbb{R}^3/\mathbb{Z}^3$:

$\int_{\mathbb{T}^3}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$

I've been told that it's simply the volume of the 'integral domain' $[0,1)^3$, i.e $1$. Though I'm having trouble understanding why this is. Going by definition (that I learned), we have to find a partition of unity subordinate to an atlas on $\mathbb{T}^3$ and integrate those locally. Is there any way to see this easily?

As a followoup question, in general can one say something about a integrating on a quotient of a smooth manifold where we know how to integrate on the original space?